# Creating a separate entity for bank transactions

Tags: credit-card, small-business

So you have your personal bank account. But I'm wondering if you can then create a separate bank account of some kind, either a business bank account or another personal one, and have the name on it be something other than your own.

This would make it so that, say you enter payment information on Amazon.com. Instead of doing this:

```
1234 5678 1234 5678
John Doe
123 Main Street
```

...and using your name and address, you could do this:

```
1234 5678 1234 5678
Alias Business
456 Alias Address
```

Or

```
1234 5678 1234 5678
Arbitrary name
789 Arbitrary address
```

Not sure if this is possible or how you would do it. It seems like if the Bank allowed you to create a card somehow (and perhaps a checking account) with an arbitrary name, you could do something like this. Wondering if one could explain how to do this briefly, or just say that it's not possible.

The only way I could see it's possible is:

1. If you actually use somebody else's real name (like your friend, for example).
2. If you actually create a real business.

But both of those have complications and such. Having a DBA (Doing Business As) halfway solves the problem but not quite. So wondering if it's possible and how it would be typically handled.

You still want the merchant to be able to associate this with a real entity to prevent problems. But at the same time it might be useful to keep a layer of abstraction in there.

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Putting a layer of anonymity between buyer and seller. `Buyer - Intermediate - Seller`.